# Updates tables without using trigger

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Can anyone tell me:

In SQL I want to insert data in two tables the same data,
You have to insert data in table1 only and data in other table(Table2) will be updated automatically.. from table1.
Condition apply: Without using triggers..

Comment: Why without using triggers? And what makes you believe that it is possible without?

Comment: Rahul, can you provide a little more context? What business goal are you trying to achieve? Why are triggers not an option?

Comment: Not sure why you can't use triggers, but if you want to insert the same data into two tables without a trigger, it's best handled via the Application layer, ie. let the client app handle the insertions and make sure of course you do everything in one transaction in case one or both of the insertions fail.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if you consider this "automatically" but you can do it in one statement using the [output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause.

```
insert into Table2 (ID, Col1, Col2)
select ID, Col1, Col2
from (
      insert into Table1 (ID, Col1, Col2)
      output inserted.ID, 
             inserted.Col1,
             inserted.Col2
      values (1, 'Col 1', 'Col 2')
     ) as T
```

Comment: good idea, you can also use output into syntax: insert into table1 output inserted.* into table2 values (1,'col1','col2')